# SAPUI5: Minify and Uglify files with Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, sapui5, minify, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm trying to get one of my `SAPUI5` apps minified on the Fiori launchpad. But I'm facing some troubles. My minified files seem to be going in a 'tmp' folder and are not seen in the Fiori launchpad. I do get some dbg files, but next to the normal files which aren't minified. So the minified files are not used, but the normal files are. I do have a minified component preload. Anyone have any advise on what I'm doing wrong?

This is my `gruntfile.js`, I'm using at the moment:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    'use strict';

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({

        uglify: {

            options: {
                mangle: true,
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true,
                    dead_code: false,
                    unused: false
                }
            },

            files: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: "<%= ref.staging%>",
                src: ["**/*.js", '!test/**', '!test_local.html'],
                dest: "<%= ref.process%>"
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'lint',
        'clean',
        'build',
        'uglify'
    ]);    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `build` task from `grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build` usually generates a `Component-preload.js` file inside your `Dist` folder. Which is in fact a minified version of your application. If you deploy the application to the FLP with a `Component-preload.js` present it loads this instead of all the single files.

Comment: Hi nlsltz, thanks for your response. I see it does that, but it somehow also loads the entire applications with files which aren't minified. In my understanding these should not be loaded when not used or loaded minified. That's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you start the application with some default URL parameters? If the `sap-ui-debug=true` is present the FLP loads the `*-dbg.js` files.

`/sap/bc/ui2/flp?sap-ui-debug=true#SemObj-display`

Comment: Nah that's the weird thing, files do not differ in wether debug mode is on or off. Even when I build the application with the default settings (without uglify just lint,clean and build). I do get a dbg file for every controller, but the controllers are untouched. Not minified or uglified at all.

Comment: you mean the source in these `*-dbg.js` files is not minified? this would be normal behavior. if you deploy the app through WebIDE everything is uploaded to the ABAP repository, but at runtime only the `Component-preload.js` is requested which has the minified source of all your files inside.

Comment: Yeah I expect the *-dbg.js files not to be minified. But e.g. It creates a Basecontroller and Basecontroller-dbg file. Both which are not minified, so I dont need to enable debug mode to see any dbg files because I see the original ones already. I do see the Component-preload.js loaded in the requests so that's good. But why does it have normal files next to the dbg files, would defeat the purpose of a dbg file?

Comment: Do the build process create the `Basecontroller.js` and `Basecontroller-dbg.js` both inside your `webapp/controller` folder or is the `*-dbg.js` file placed inside the `dist/controller` folder? Did you check the BSP application through SE80 transaction in your ABAP backend to clarify that really the normal source files AND the dbg source files are uploaded?

Comment: Hey, yeah both files are obviously created in the dist/controller folder and I do see them in the SE80 transaction.

Comment: i've just looked into a project of mine. same behavior as you described, got both files created in `dist/controller` folder and i see only the normal files in bsp application. but when i open the app through flp it only loads the `component-preload.js`.

Comment: Ah I see, then the only question I have is; What is the use of the '-dbg' files. If you look at the sources, I see the original files aswell in sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap . In these files I'm able to debug the application aswell, so what's the use of the -dbg files?

Comment: i think they are created from the grunt task which is rarly updated. i hope the new build tools are not a blackbox like the sap-bestpractice-build task as it is right now :)

Comment: Ah yeah, could be. Seemed kinda pointless that's why I was confused. I tried to still give that same functionality by adding a 'uglify' and a 'copy' task after the build. So it would replace the original controllers by minified controllers, but can't get the configuration right to copy from the 'tmp' to replace the original ones.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you post a screenshot of Network Tab in Chrome Debugger, where we can see all loaded modules.

The following docu might be helpful:
[grunt-openui5](https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5#openui5_preload), [Best Practices](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/29/sapui5-application-startup-performance-best-practices), [Advanced Topics](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/19/sapui5-application-startup-performance-advanced-topics),

Comment: [Accelerate your UI5 application with component-preload minified](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/08/accelerate-your-ui5-application-with-component-preload-minified) and

[UI5 Application: Approaches for Performance Improvement](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/01/19/ui5-application-approaches-for-performance-improvement)